# Scalar / Dot product

Tags: bilinear-form

I have a simple question about Scalar / Dot product.
(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product)

Say f is a bilinear form. I have to tell if f defines a dot product.
I didn't understand what I should do, what does f has to satisfy so it can be called a "dot product" ?

thanks

Comment: I hope this isn't a dumb question, but have you tried looking up “dot product” in the index of your textbook and seeing if it refers you to the book's definition of what properties a bilinear form must have to be considered a dot product?

Comment: Actually, I don't have a textbook (and yes it's a dumb question), sorry I just really don't know its definition, been looking over the internet and thought I'd get some proper answer here

Comment: You said “I have to tell if $f$ defines a dot product”. Why do you have to do that?

Comment: That's the question (homework). (I know f(x,y)=...)

Comment: I didn't mean your question was dumb; I meant I hoped *my* question wasn't dumb.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $V$ be a vector space over $\Bbb R$.

A bilinear form $f:V\times V\to\Bbb R$ is a *scalar product* if it satisfies

1. $f(x,y)=f(y,x)$ for all $x,y\in V$ (*symmetric*)
2. $f(x,x)> 0$ for all nonzero $x\in V$ (*positive definite*)

Comment: See also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_product_space